# OpenShift Tomcat app deployment startup error

Tags: deployment, openshift, tomcat6

I have an old "webapp v2.3" app which I've deployed locally to Tomcat v6.0.44
but I can't get this app deployed to OpenShift Tomcat v6.0.44, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\username>rhc tail  apps
==> app-root/logs/jbossews.log <==
SEVERE: The web application [/equip2call] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 27, 2015 3:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/equip2call] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Sep 27, 2015 3:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/equip2call] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
[equip2call] INFO [main] Logger.info(51) | Logging using commons-logging.
Sep 27, 2015 3:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.6.120.1-8080
Sep 27, 2015 3:01:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 27697 ms
```

My web.xml skeleton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  ...
</web-app>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue myself by simply changing the DB connection URL from localhost to the {OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}